# Top 10 keywords PHP in a string

Tags: php, arrays, string, keyword

I made a complex array of keywords when my goal is to present the top 10 words are in the string.

### b) I just want to introduce a words of importance rather than words like  "The,That,to,a...".

***The Full Code:***

```
$str= $db_tag;
    $tok = strtok($str, ", ");
    $subStrStart = 0;

    while ($tok !== false) {
        preg_match_all("/\b" . preg_quote($tok, "/") . "\b/", substr($str, $subStrStart), $m);
        if(count($m[0]) >= 10)
            echo "'" . $tok . "' found more than 10 times, exaclty: " . count($m[0]) . "<br>";
        $subStrStart += strlen($tok);
        $tok = strtok(", ");
    }
```

***My string:***

```
$db_tag="The,Economy,Could,Be,Given,A,Post,Brexit,Vote,Vote,Vote,Vote,Boost,This,Week,As,Expectations,Mount,That,The,Bank,Bank,Bank,Bank,Bank,Of,England,England,England,England,England,Will,Cut,Economy,Economy,Economy,Brexit,Brexit,Brexit,Brexit";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should explode your string and work with array functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "Top 10" you mean "10 Most-Used Words" in a string, separated by commas `,`, you can do:

```
$string = "The,Economy,Could,Be,Given,A,Post,Brexit,Vote,Vote,Vote,Vote,Boost,This,Week,As,Expectations,Mount,That,The,Bank,Bank,Bank,Bank,Bank,Of,England,England,England,England,England,Will,Cut,Economy,Economy,Economy,Brexit,Brexit,Brexit,Brexit";

//Create array of words split by ","
$words = explode(",",$string);

//Create an empty array to hold data
$wordData = [];

foreach($words as $word){
    //Convert to lower case (for uniformity)
    $word = strtolower($word);

    //Add to an array if doesn't exist; if it does,
    //add to the number
    if(isset($wordData[$word])){
        $wordData[$word]++;
    } else $wordData[$word] = 1;
}

//Order $wordData array by number
arsort($wordData);

print_r($wordData);
```

This will output:

> Array
>   (
>       [England] => 5
>       [Bank] => 5
>       [Brexit] => 5
>       [Vote] => 4
>       [Economy] => 4
>       [The] => 2
>       [Expectations] => 1
>       [Will] => 1
>       [Of] => 1
>       [That] => 1
>       [Mount] => 1
>       [This] => 1
>       [As] => 1
>       [Week] => 1
>       [Boost] => 1
>       [Post] => 1
>       [A] => 1
>       [Given] => 1
>       [Be] => 1
>       [Could] => 1
>       [Cut] => 1
>   )

---

To filter out specific words:

```
//Establish array of words to filter
$filterWords = ["the", "is", "are", "of", "that"];

//Remove those words from the array created earlier
foreach($filterWords as $fw){
    if(isset($wordData[$fw])) unset($wordData[$fw]);
}

print_r($wordData);
```

This will output:

> Array ( [england] => 5 [bank] => 5 [brexit] => 5 [vote] => 4 [economy] => 4 [expectations] => 1 [will] => 1 [mount] => 1 [this] => 1 [as] => 1 [week] => 1 [boost] => 1 [post] => 1 [a] => 1 [given] => 1 [be] => 1 [could] => 1 [cut] => 1 )

Comment: YES, Excellent thanks you. I have two questions. A. There is a way to change $topTen at the end to a string like $db_tag (with just the tagwords) B. Is there a way to filter out words like "THE, IS, ARE , OF , THAT"? tnx again @ben

Comment: @alainmardo I added that functionality to the answer. I also added a line that converts all the strings to lowercase so that it's easier to manage the strings. Hope this helps.

Comment: perfect @ben tnx. any way to add in the end the output ($worddata) after print_r... bring back the words from the array to a new string $new_string = "The,Economy,Could,Be,Given,A,Post,Brexit,Vote"; tnx again

Comment: Have a look at [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). `$newString = implode(",",$wordData);`

Comment: hi ben, the implode give me numbers (counting) and not not the Keywords. tnx again

Comment: `$newString = implode(",",array_keys($wordData));`

Comment: Perfect tnx again @ben

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$db_tag = "The,Economy,Could,Be,Given,A,Post,Brexit,Vote,Vote,Vote,Vote,Boost,This,Week,As,Expectations,Mount,That,The,Bank,Bank,Bank,Bank,Bank,Of,England,England,England,England,England,Will,Cut,Economy,Economy,Economy,Brexit,Brexit,Brexit,Brexit";

$stopWords = array(
    "the", "to", "in", "a", "of", "is", "that", "will", "and", "be"
);

// Convert to array and filter out stopwords.
$words = array_filter(function ($value) {
    return !in_array($value, $stopwords);
}, explode(',', $db_tag));

$counts = array_count_values($words);
asort($counts);
$topTen = array_reverse(array_slice($counts, -10, null, true));

var_dump($topTen);
```

You should see:

```
php > var_dump($topTen);
array(10) {
  ["England"]=>
  int(5)
  ["Bank"]=>
  int(5)
  ["Brexit"]=>
  int(5)
  ["Economy"]=>
  int(4)
  ["Vote"]=>
  int(4)
  ["The"]=>
  int(2)
  ["Post"]=>
  int(1)
  ["Given"]=>
  int(1)
  ["A"]=>
  int(1)
  ["Could"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

First, we split the string into an array with [`explode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). Then, we return an array of unique array values with [`array_count_values()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), associated with the count of their occurrence in the string.

Next, we sort the array in-place by value using [`asort()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php). Then, we slice off the last 10 elements from the array (the highest ones) with [`array_slice()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and then reverse it with [`array_reverse()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) to put them in descending order (optional).

Comment: Excellent thanks you. I have two questions. A. There is a way to change $topTen at the end to a string like $db_tag (with just the tagwords) B. Is there a way to filter out words  like "THE, IS, ARE , OF , THAT"? tnx @will

Comment: @alainmardo create a blacklist for `B` containing the words you want to exclude

Comment: What do you mean by just the keywords? You don't want the counts?

Comment: Hi again. i want the counts and i want the string back ( for display in the article the  keywords). <?php
$words = explode(',', $db_tag2); 
?>
<?php foreach($words as $word) { if(!empty($word))?>
<a href="?t=<?php echo $word;?>"><?php echo $word;?></a>
<?php } ?>

Comment: array(10) { ["The"]=> int(64) ["To"]=> int(48) ["In"]=> int(20) ["A"]=> int(19) ["Of"]=> int(19) ["Is"]=> int(16) ["That"]=> int(14) ["Will"]=> int(13) ["And"]=> int(13) ["Be"]=> int(12) } with another article he give me this output... there are a way to remove words like "THE, TO, IS..." tnx again @Will

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode and an array:

```
$db_tag="The,Economy,Could,Be,Given,A,Post,Brexit,Vote,Vote,Vote,Vote,Boost,This,Week,As,Expectations,Mount,That,The,Bank,Bank,Bank,Bank,Bank,Of,England,England,England,England,England,Will,Cut,Economy,Economy,Economy,Brexit,Brexit,Brexit,Brexit";
$array = array();
foreach (explode(',', $db_tag) as $val) 
{
    if(!isset($array[$val]))
    {
        $array[$val] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $array[$val]++;
    }
}
arsort($array);
print_r($array);
```

will output:

```
Array
(
    [England] => 5
    [Bank] => 5
    [Brexit] => 5
    [Vote] => 4
    [Economy] => 4
    [The] => 2
    [Expectations] => 1
    [Will] => 1
    [Of] => 1
    [That] => 1
    [Mount] => 1
    [This] => 1
    [As] => 1
    [Week] => 1
    [Boost] => 1
    [Post] => 1
    [A] => 1
    [Given] => 1
    [Be] => 1
    [Could] => 1
    [Cut] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the bellow function to exctract search keywords from a string

```
function getKeywords($string)
{
    $string = "North Korea has recently introduced a sweeping new law which seeks to stamp out any kind of foreign influence - harshly punishing anyone caught with foreign films, clothing or even using slang. But why?Yoon Mi-so says she was 11 when she first saw a man executed for being caught with a South Korean drama.    His entire neighbourhood was ordered to watch. If you didn't, it would be classed as treason, she told the BBC from her home in Seoul.        The North Korean guards were making sure everyone knew the penalty for smuggling illicit videos was death. I have a strong memory of the man who was blindfolded, I can still see his tears flow down. That was traumatic for me. The blindfold was completely drenched in his tears. ";
    $vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"];
    $ignore = ["th","thy","sh"];
    $string = str_replace($vowels, "", $string);

//Create array of words split by ","
$words = explode(" ",$string);

//Create an empty array to hold data
$wordData = [];

foreach($words as $word){
    //Convert to lower case (for uniformity)
    $word = trim(strtolower($word));
    if(strlen($word)<3)
        continue;
    if(array_search($word, $ignore)>-1) continue;
    //Add to an array if doesn't exist; if it does,
    //add to the number
    if(isset($wordData[$word])){
        $wordData[$word]++;
    } else $wordData[$word] = 1;
}

//Order $wordData array by number
arsort($wordData);

$x = (array_keys($wordData));
$result = "";
$count = 0;

foreach ($wordData as $key => $value) {
    $count++;
    $result .=$key . ",";
    if($count==10) break;
}

return $result;
}
```